# Приложение на phonegap для выбора изображения

Tags: javascript, phonegap, gallery, phonegap-api

Возможно ли сделать приложение на phonegap, что бы оно было в списке приложения,  через которые можно выбрать изображение (например когда прикрепляем фото в приложении VK).

То есть когда мы нажимаем прикрепить изображение у нас появляется список приложений через которые можно выбрать нужное фото.

Как настроить приложение что бы оно появлялось там и как передавать нужно фото?

[image: Пример списка приложений]

Comment: Быть может нужно лишь запросить файл, а андроид уже сам выдаст окно и вернёт файл? С сабжем не работал, просто предположил что такой выбор - это вотчина системы, а не приложения.

Comment: @Other сторонние приложения как-то попадаются же в список выбора файла, значит можно

Comment: Регистрируются по теме (обработчик plain/text) в системе?

Comment: я думаю настолько не можно сделать, гугл дает некоторые запросы по вашему вопросу phonegap choose image from gallery

Comment: возможно это https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/03/12/selecting-multiple-images-in-a-phonegapcordova-app/ ?